# React Native Error: Request failed with status code 499

Tags: react-native, hybrid-mobile-app

I'm trying to fetch data from an API hosted on Heroku in a React Native app on an IOS simulator, and I keep getting this error `Error: Request failed with status code 499` which occurs after a long period of time (close to a minute) from the time the API call is initiated.

The same API calls work well in Android emulator.

Please what could be causing this how can I fix it?

Comment: Can u check to see if the call from the react native IOS app reaches your  REST service. If the call doesn't react the REST layer then it might be some issue with any proxy setting or something similar on your IOS Simulator which blocks the outgoing calls

Answer (score 0):

If anybody is still experiencing these issues, make sure that you're not sending a body in your get requests. I had the issue where I sent a `GET` request with

```
{
  method: 'GET',
  url: '<url>',
  body: {}
}
```

because the body was accidentally appended to the request.